# CSP nonces with Cloudflare Workers

Tags: nonce, cloudflare

Like this blog, I use Cloudflare Workers to inject CSP (Content Security Policy) nonce in headers : https://scotthelme.co.uk/csp-nonces-the-easy-way-with-cloudflare-workers/

This is functional.
Next, I need to inject the nonce into all script tags. I use this script (in functions.php) :

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script', 10, 3 );
function add_nonce_to_script( $tag, $handle, $source ) {

$search = "type='text/javascript'";
$replace = "type='text/javascript' nonce='<?= html_escape($cspNonce); ?>'";
$subject = $tag;

$output = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
return $output;
}
```

The result is not the expected one, I get this kind of code :

```
script type="text/javascript" nonce="&lt;?= html_escape(); ?&gt;&lt;![CDATA[html5-dom-document-internal-cdata"
```

The problem probably comes from this line, but I don't know how to correct it :

```
$replace = "type='text/javascript' nonce='<?= html_escape($cspNonce); ?>'";
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: You can't put PHP opening tags inside a PHP string, that doesn't make sense because you are already inside PHP. You need to join/concatenate the strings together. This isn't a WordPress problem but rather a misunderstanding of beginner level PHP. This is essentially what you've tried to do: `<?php <?php ?> ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, you are absolutely right.

I also corrected my mistake. I'll post the code if it helps.

Code for Cloudflare Workers: https://gist.github.com/richie5um/b2999177b27095af13ec619e44742116

Code for Wordpress :

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_nonce_to_script', 10, 3 );
function add_nonce_to_script( $tag, $handle, $source ) {
$search = "type='text/javascript'";
$replace = "type='text/javascript' nonce=''";
$subject = $tag;

$output = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
return $output;
}
```